# My activity keep show the dialog, It seem don't do the doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My activity keep show the  dialog, It seem don't do the doInBackground. It keep should the "Loading"  screen . 
 Here is my code :

```
private class MapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected Context context;

    public MapTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(context, 1);
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            try {
                String countryName=country.getTitle();
                List<Address> address = new Geocoder(context).getFromLocationName(countryName, 1);
                if (address == null) {
                    Log.e(null,  "Not found");
                } else {
                    Address loc = address.get(0);
                    Log.e(null, loc.getLatitude() + " " + loc.getLongitude());
                    LatLng pos = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 6));
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ASYNC", "ERROR : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `dialog.dismiss()` anywhere. You should do it in the `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void... aVoid) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is doing the doInBackground stuff, the problem is that you aren't dismissing the dialog in onPostExecute() method

Just add `dialog.dismiss()` in onPostExecute method.